# permission denied error cloning git repositry with npm on LinuxLite

Tags: linux, permissions, git, sudo

I am using LinuxLite V5 and I am trying to clone one repository from git using npm V8.3.0 but it throws this exception:

> fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone7tt2X1': Permission denied

I try all of these commands but no progress!!!

- `npm i -g https://github.com/nextcloud/strengthify`
- `npm i https://github.com/nextcloud/strengthify`
- `npm install --prefix=$HOME/.local --global https://github.com/MorrisJobke/strengthify.git`

I also run all of these commands in with sudo and **sudo su** mode but there was not any progress.

I also checked folder owner and group and permissions. it is the result:

```
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root  4096 jun 13 14:50 .npm
```

How can I solve this problem?